# Enabling a Scrollable box if a checked box has been ticked

Tags: java, jframe

What i want is to happen is a Scrollable box be made visible when two check boxes have been selected

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 10, 5, 3);//pos is temp
    contentPane.add(panel);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    panel.add(scrollPane);
```

and in the box the user should be able to input a number.

so what i did for that was to add a box inside the scroll pane and setting the visibility to false.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    textField = new JTextField();
    scrollPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(6);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.setVisible(false);
```

but the text field does not show.

And also a listener

```
    ActionListener al = (ActionEvent e) -> {
        if (e.getSource() == chA || e.getSource() == chB) {
            chckbx1.setEnabled(true);
            //setting the panel to visible when box a or B and chckbx1 has been selected 
            if (e.getSource() == chckbx1) {
                panel.setVisible(true);

            }
        }
    };
    chA.addActionListener(al);
    chB.addActionListener(al);
```

but atm this doesn't work, i anyone could kindly help i would be grateful.

Here is a link to the full code >> http://pastebin.com/v689BB8A

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this and see where you are wrong.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                Test window = new Test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JCheckBox chA = new JCheckBox("text");
        chA.setFont(new Font("Adobe Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        frame.getContentPane().add(chA);

        JCheckBox chB = new JCheckBox("text");
        chB.setFont(new Font("Adobe Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        frame.getContentPane().add(chB);

        JCheckBox chckbx1 = new JCheckBox("text");
        chckbx1.setFont(new Font("Adobe Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        chckbx1.setEnabled(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbx1);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 5);
        scrollPane.add(textArea);
        textArea.setColumns(6);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        panel.setVisible(false);

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == chA || e.getSource() == chB) {
                    chckbx1.setEnabled(true);
                }

                if (e.getSource() == chckbx1) {
                    panel.setVisible(true);
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        chA.addActionListener(al);
        chB.addActionListener(al);
        chckbx1.addActionListener(al);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you basic requirement is

> when box a or B and chckbx1 has been selected

show the `JScrollPane`.

So, based on your code...

```
if (e.getSource() == chA || e.getSource() == chB) {
    chckbx1.setEnabled(true);
    //setting the panel to visible when box a or B and chckbx1 has been selected 
    if (e.getSource() == chckbx1) {
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It's actually impossible for you to display the `panel`, as it's impossible for the `source` of the `ActionEvent` to be either the `chA` or `chB` AND `chckbx1` `JCheckBox` at the same time, instead you should simply check the `selected` state of the `JCheckBox`s

For example...

```
if ((chA.isSelected() || chB.isSelected()) && chckbx1.isSelected()) {
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}
```

Normally, I'd encourage the use of a `CardLayout`, but that might a little but of over kill for this.

Runnable example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        JCheckBox chA = new JCheckBox("A");
        chA.setFont(new Font("Adobe Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        frame.getContentPane().add(chA, gbc);
//      chA.setEnabled(false);

        JCheckBox chB = new JCheckBox("B");
        chB.setFont(new Font("Adobe Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        frame.getContentPane().add(chB, gbc);
//      chB.setEnabled(false);

        JCheckBox chckbx1 = new JCheckBox("C");
        chckbx1.setFont(new Font("Adobe Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbx1, gbc);
        chckbx1.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel, gbc);

        textField = new JTextField();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textField);
//      scrollPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(6);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel.setVisible(false);

        ActionListener al = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (chA.isSelected() || chB.isSelected()) {
                chckbx1.setEnabled(true);
            }
            //setting the panel to visible when box a or B and chckbx1 has been selected 
            if ((chA.isSelected() || chB.isSelected()) && chckbx1.isSelected()) {
                panel.setVisible(true);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        };
        chA.addActionListener(al);
        chB.addActionListener(al);
        chckbx1.addActionListener(al);

    }

}
```